# Jest/Enzyme | Redux prop is not defined in test

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jestjs, enzyme

I am using React-Redux, in a connected component and I want to test if a particular component is rendered. In order for that component to render 2 things must be true:

1. ListUsers must be an empty array
2. The securityMode should be basic.

I have already defined the securityMode in my component Props, with no problem. But the `ListUsers prop`, is coming through redux.

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    securityMode: securityModeSelector(state),
    usersList: state.users.list,
    usersListFetching: state.users.listFetching
  };
}
```

This is my component logic that should be tested:

```
renderNoResourceComponent = () => {
    const { usersList, securityMode } = this.props;
    const { selectedGroups } = this.state;

    const filteredData = filterUserData(usersList, selectedGroups);
    if (filteredData && filteredData.length === 0 && securityMode === 'BASIC') {
      return (
        <div className="center-block" data-test="no-resource-component">
          <NoResource>
            .............
          </NoResource>
        </div>
      );
    }
    return null;
  };
```

And this is the test I wrote:

```
  describe('BASIC securityMode without Data', () => {
    const props = {
      securityMode: 'BASIC',
      listUsers: () => {},
      usersList: [] // This is the redux prop
    };
    it('should render NoResource component', () => {
      const wrapper = shallow(<UsersOverviewScreen {...props} />);
      const renderUsers = wrapper.find(`[data-test="no-resource-component"]`);
      expect(renderUsers).toHaveLength(1);
    });
  });
```

But I get an error saying the `userLists` is not defined. How do I pass this redux prop so my component would pass. `I also need that prop for another set of tests, that needs data, which I need to mock.

Can someone guide me through this? Thank you..

Comment: From what I am reading, I need to use something like redux-mock-store, export both components `connected and not`, and pass the data from there. But I don't seem to get the methodology. I would appreciate it if you could guide me through it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is export the component before its connocted to Redux and pass all the props it needs manually:

```
export class UsersOverviewScreen extends Component {
  // ... your functions
  render() {
    return (
      // ... your componont
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    securityMode: securityModeSelector(state),
    usersList: state.users.list,
    usersListFetching: state.users.listFetching
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(UsersOverviewScreen);
```

Now, in your tests you can `import { UsersOverviewScreen } form 'path/to/UsersOverviewScreen';`. You can create the props and pass it to the component like this:

```
const mockUsersLists = jest.fn(() => usersList || []);
const wrapper = shallow(<UsersOverviewScreen {...props} usersList={mockUsersLists} />);
```

Comment: I have already done that. I read on this article, that I should either user something like redux-mock-strore to simulate the behavior or do something like this:
`const mockUsersLists = jest.fn(() => usersList || []);`, and in my shallow do this: `const wrapper = shallow(<UsersOverviewScreen {...props} usersList={mockUsersLists} />);`

Which is working, but not sure, if it is the right solution...

Comment: I have accepted your solution. Could you please add my addittion, just to be a completed answer to the question... Thanks!!

Comment: @DimitrisEfst Done 